# PHP - How to combine two arrays with different number of elements?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

**One:**

```
array(4) { 
 [0]=> array(2) { 
     [0]=> string(19) "Ford" 
     [1]=> string(1) "1" 
 } 
 [1]=> array(2) { 
     [0]=> string(15) "Chevrolet" 
     [1]=> string(1) "1" 
 } 
 [2]=> array(2) { 
     [0]=> string(7) "VW" 
     [1]=> string(1) "1" 
 } 
 [3]=> array(2) { 
     [0]=> string(4) "Fiat" 
     [1]=> string(1) "3" 
 } 
}
```

**Two:**

```
array(6) { 
    [0]=> string(7) "#581845" 
    [1]=> string(7) "#900C3F" 
    [2]=> string(7) "#C70039" 
    [3]=> string(7) "#FF5733" 
    [4]=> string(7) "#FFC300" 
    [5]=> string(7) "#DAF7A6" 
}
```

Now, I need the first array combining with the second, excluding the elements of the second array that are not used by the first. At the end, I want to receive an array like:

```
[0]=> {
        [0]=> "Ford", 
        [1]=> "1", 
        [2]=>"#581845"
      } 
        [1]=>  
        ... 
      }
```

Comment: So you have obviously tried to do this somehow. Can you show us what you have tried

Comment: I tried to use array_combine, but the two arrays need to have the both number of elements. I also tried to use two foreach combined.

Comment: Your desired final array format, doesn't exist in reality. You should clarify.  @RobRuchte provided an answer that seems to be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you always have more colors than auto makes, you can do this:

```
$makes = [
    [
        "Ford",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "Chevrolet",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "VW",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "Fiat",
        "3"
    ]
];

$colors = [
    "#581845",
    "#900C3F",
    "#C70039",
    "#FF5733",
    "#FFC300",
    "#DAF7A6"
];

foreach($makes as &$currMakeTuple)
{
    $currMakeTuple[] = array_shift($colors);
}

print_r($makes);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ford
            [1] => 1
            [2] => #581845
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Chevrolet
            [1] => 1
            [2] => #900C3F
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => VW
            [1] => 1
            [2] => #C70039
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Fiat
            [1] => 3
            [2] => #FF5733
        )

)
```

You should probably check that condition and have a contingency for it.

Comment: first, thanks. But, your code return just one line in new array. I Need to have all elements of the first array (makes) into the new array.

Comment: I get all four in my test case.

Answer (score 0):

Another one solution. Independent of the number of colors. Will add to brands only those colors which keys are equal to the brands' keys.

```
$brands = [
    ['Ford', 1],
    ['Chevrolet', 1],
    ['VW', 1],
    ['Fiat', 3],
];

$colors = [
    '#581845',
    '#900C3F',
    '#C70039',
    '#FF5733',
    '#FFC300',
    '#DAF7A6',
];

array_walk($brands, function(&$value, $key, $colors) {
    if (isset($colors[$key])) {
        $value = array_merge($value, [$colors[$key]]);
    }
}, $colors);

print_r($brands);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying you should do it this way, but I thought it was worth showing an alternative that used array functions instead:

```
var_dump(array_map(function($make, $color) {
    $make[] = $color;
    return $make;
}, $makes, array_slice($colors, 0, count($makes))));
```

I used:

1. array_slice to reduce the $colors array, should it be too long.
2. array_map with a lambda (anonymous function) that will apply the lambda to each element and return the final array upon completion.